# Getting front value from array/json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to get my image value wich could be images/thispicture.png for example.

I have an Array or Json with some values, but the problem is i only want the image from array.

This is what i get now from the array:

```
{"image_intro":"images\/16748007940_1cc8f06622_small.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}"><img src="/{"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}"><img src="/{"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
```

I only want the "image_intro" how can i do this?

when i json_decode i get this output:

```
["image_intro"]=>
  string(39) "images/16748007940_1cc8f06622_small.jpg"
  ["float_intro"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_intro_alt"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_intro_caption"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_fulltext"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["float_fulltext"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_fulltext_alt"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_fulltext_caption"]=>
  string(0) ""
```

What to do? how can i get this to be a string i just can echo out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $array["image_intro"] ?

Comment: `echo $yourArrayName["image_intro"]`; is just enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$array["image_intro"]`,this will give you the value of image_intro.  check out the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

try to following

```
$array["image_intro"]
```